# Cannot configure EJB Pooling in Wildfly 8

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, connection-pooling

I am using EJB 2.1 and deploying them in Wildfly 8. We have defined a connection pool where the max number of connections are 100 and timeout is 3 mins. But my issue is more than 100 requests are coming within 3 mins, so it is unable to get more connections and throwing Exception.

To solve this we are planning to implement EJB pooling and set the max pool size as 100. So by this way if more than 100 simultaneous requests come it will not be served and will wait.

I have two questions here:
1. Is this the default behaviour of EJB pool that 100 simultaneous requests will be served and if the 101th request comes, it will wait or the 101th request will throw exception or it depends on the server?

2. How to configure EJB pooling in Wildfly 8?

Comment: Using an EJB pool will only move your problem somewhere else. You need to figure out a way to reduce your SQL query execution times. Your users may not tolerate routinely waiting 60-180 seconds for a page response. Are you using CMP EJBs?

Comment: No, we are not using CMP.